# Express / Node.js / WebStorm debugging is very slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am trying to customize Node.js based web application: https://github.com/Mailtrain-org/mailtrain

I want to do debugging. I did some configuration for launching the app
 as you can see config in the following image:

[image]

But debugging is not working and its very slow to start. It take 5 min to start debugging.

```
/Users/Calm/.nvm/versions/node/v7.0.0/bin/node --debug-brk=50039
--nolazy index.js Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:50039 info Using local auth  info sql Database check completed info Express WWW server listening on port 3000 verb UTC Updating timezone offsets Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:50039
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at net.js:1397:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Although it says port is already in using, but I didn't start any other debug process.

Would you like to help me to make this work?